# How do I prevent the servlet from escaping the double quotes inside a response

Tags: java, tomcat, libcurl

I am posting data with embedded double quotes from a libcurl client to a Tomcat servlet. 
The servlet reads the data and sends it back to my client.

What I send looks like this

```
{
   "id": 1,
   "name": "Foo",
}
```

But what I receive from the servlet looks like this

```
{
   \"id\": 1,
   \"name\": \"Foo\"
}
```

i.e. all the double quotes get escaped.

How do I prevent the servlet from escaping the quotes?
My servlet is doing something like this inside the doPost method

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
                      HttpServletResponse response)
        throws IOException, ServletException
{
    BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();
    StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
    char[] buffer = new char[4 * 1024];
    int len = 0;
    while (len >= 0) { 
        len = reader.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length); 
        if (len > 0) { 
            content.append(buffer, 0, len);
        }
    }

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter(); 
    out.print(content.toString())
}
```

***Edit***
This fixes my problem.

```
URLEncoder.encode(content.toString(),"UTF-8")
```

Comment: StringBuilder is null but then you append to it, in that method at least.

Comment: @Vulcan Thanks. Fixed. That was a typo from copy paste, the buffer is properly initialized in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encode the string before you write it.

Comment: This is the right answer. Is there a newer method for encoding? I get a deprected warning using URLEncoder.encode

Comment: Use the `encode` method that accepts an encoding as the second argument.